# How can I properly deserialize Response format

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

This is the error I get after calling an AWS Lambda function:

> An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Can not construct instance of IntentResponse: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Thanks, your pizza has been ordered.') at [Source: "Thanks, your pizza has been ordered."; line: 1, column: 1]

```
    exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const response = {

        "dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled or Failed",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText or SSML",
      "content": "Thanks, your pizza has been ordered."
    } 
  }
    };
    return response.dialogAction.message.content;
};
```

Comment: I think it is saying that it is expecting an `IntentResponse`, but you are providing a `String`. It's hard to know what you are doing since you are not showing any code, but I presuming you are using [Lambda Function Input Event and Response Format - Amazon Lex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format). Try: `return response;`

Comment: thanks for the reply, it was simply setting contentType to PLainText

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you took your response from one of the example docs:

```
"dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled or Failed",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText or SSML",
      "content": "This example won't work as is."
    } 
}
```

Many have made the same mistake, but for both `fulfillmentState` and `contentType`, you must choose either one OR the other example values shown there, and exactly as shown with correct capitalization.

So to clarify:

Set `fulfillmentState` to either `Fulfilled` or `Failed`

And

Set `contentType` of message to either `PlainText` or `SSML`

```
"dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText",
      "content": "This is a proper example response."
    } 
}
```